# How To Login To Terminal (OSX) Without Quitting Or Closing Window

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I like to keep my windows open on my work machine so when I arrive in the mornings, I don't have to go through the process of opening them all again; and opening all my files. I can pick up where I left off.

I `exit` the Terminal and quit. Then the next morning I open the Terminal again.

I'd like to just `exit` but keep the window open (and hide it); and then login in the mornings.

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 1):

[GNU screen](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach, close the window, and in the morning
`screen -r` to reattach, whatever you were doing is still there, but hidden.

When you close the window after detaching a screen, the process runs in the background hidden.

Back in the old days, people would have dozens or even hundreds of text based games, summoned at any time with `screen -r zork`

[Here is a tutorial about screen.](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/285795-taking-command-of-the-terminal-with-gnu-screen-)

Comment: Get it at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/

Comment: Learn it from http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/285795-taking-command-of-the-terminal-with-gnu-screen-

Comment: You can [edit] your answer at any time; no need to post a comment if there's nobody to reply to.